# Conceptual Question: difference between Line Integral with respect to ds versus dx or dy

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, line-integrals

I am doing vector calculus and am having trouble gaining intuition/understanding about the difference between a line integral with respect to ds, and line integrals with respect to dx.

$$\int_C f(x,y)\ ds$$

$$\int_C f(x,y)\ dx$$ or $$\int_C f(x,y)\ dy$$

Notably, in the consequence that:

$$\int_C f(x,y)\ ds=\int_{-C} f(x,y)\ ds$$

But:

$$\int_C f(x,y)\ dx=-\int_{-C} f(x,y)\ dx$$

Would anyone have pointers to better understand these nuances?
Thanks!

Comment: It has to do with the parameterization of the line.  When integrating dS were integrating per unit length of the line

Answer (score 2):

These are very good questions, and in trying to understand the differences it helps to have a little insight into this topic from the slightly more formal point of view of integrating forms on curves.

For ease of reference, call these integrals (1) and (2) respectively.

$\int_C f(x,y)\ ds$

$\int_C f(x,y)\ dx$

To be sure, (1) and (2) are not the same integral but differently parametrized. They are truly distinct.

Assume throughout that $C$ is a smooth or piecewise smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that $f$ is continuous on some open set $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains $C$.  That is, the usual basic assumptions for line integrals.

Also, this entire discussion would be valid in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>2$ but we can stick to $n=2$ without any real loss of generality.

(1) is a line integral of a *scalar field* (real-valued function) along a curve $C$ with respect to arc-length $ds$ and is calculated as:

$\int_C f(x,y)\ ds = \int_a ^b f(x(t),y(t))\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\space dt$

where $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ parametrize $C$ for $a\leq t\leq b$.

For (2), rather than try to view it as a special case of (1), which it really is not, it's better to view it as a special case of a line integral

$\int_C f(x,y)\space dx+g(x,y)\space dy$

which is often written as

$\int_C P\space dx+Q\space dy$

where $Q=g(x,y)=0\space$ in this case.

In this case, $\vec F=(P,Q)$ is a vector field on $D$ and we are integrating it along $C$ (vs. integrating a scalar function in (1)).

In this case the line integral is evaluated as

$\int_C P\space dx+Q\space dy = \int_a^b \vec F (\vec r(t))\cdot \vec r'(t)\space dt$

where $\vec r(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ for $a\leq t\leq b$ and when $Q=g(x,y)=0$ we just get

$\int_a^b f(x(t),y(t))\space x'(t)\space dt $

and comparing to the evaluation of (1) this is not a special case.

As to your observation on signs when reversing orientation of $C$:

Integral (1) is an *unoriented* line integral. If $f(x,y)=1$ this calculates the  the arc length of $C$ and we would like this to be the same positive value regardless of which way $C$ is traversed. Clearly if we parametrize as above and then integrate from $b$ to $a$ the integral will reverse sign however if the unoriented integral is required to be on an interval $a\leq t\leq b$ it will not even under an orientation-reversing parametrization.

Integral (2) on the other hand as the integral of a vector field (its associated 1-form) on a curve (1-chain) is naturally an *oriented* integral and as defined will naturally reverse sign upon reversing the orientation.

Comment: This was very helpful – thank you very much!!